# Delphi 10.3 functions CharUpper and CharUpperW differ Delphi 10.4

Tags: delphi

Does somebody know the reason why `CharUpper` and `CharUpperW` declaration in Delphi 10.3 is different than in Delphi 10.4.

Correct declaration in Delphi 10.3

```
    var
      chr   :WideChar;
    begin      
      chr := WideChar(CharUpperW(PWideChar('a'))); //chr = 'A'
//    chr := WideChar(CharUpperW(WideChar('a')));  //raise exeption: "access violation...
```

Correct declaration in Delphi 10.4

```
    var
      chr   :WideChar;
    begin   
//    chr := WideChar(CharUpperW(PWideChar('a')));  //raise exeption: "access violation...
      chr := WideChar(CharUpperW(WideChar('a')));   //chr = 'A'
```

**EDIT**: The Remy Lebeau expalanation is right about PWideChar but there is still differences about Delphi version 10.4 and earlier versions!

**Lebeau expalanation** code sample compile in version 10.4 and earlier versions, but the output of function is different. All versions before 10.4 get correct output "A"!

```
var
  char , chr : WideChar;
begin
  chr := 'a';
  char := WideChar(CharUpperW(PWideChar(chr)));
end;
```

This sample under 10.4 doesn't work correct the output is random character.

And of course...
The declaration of function `CharUpperW` it the same in boath versions of Delphi.

```
LPWSTR = PWideChar; 
function CharUpperW(lpsz: LPWSTR): LPWSTR; stdcall;**
```

EDIT: added disassembled code under 10.4

```
umCommon.pas.114: chr := 'a';
0064C52C 66BB6100         mov bx,$0061
umCommon.pas.115: char := WideChar(CharUpperW(PWideChar(chr)));
0064C530 8D45FC           lea eax,[ebp-$04]
0064C533 8BD3             mov edx,ebx
0064C535 E8EEE7DBFF       call @UStrFromWChar
0064C53A 8B45FC           mov eax,[ebp-$04]
0064C53D E8C2E7DBFF       call @UStrToPWChar
0064C542 50               push eax
0064C543 E8809DDCFF       call CharUpperW
```

Disassembled code under 10.3

```
umCommon.pas.114: chr := 'a';
0063A905 66BB6100         mov bx,$0061
umCommon.pas.115: char := WideChar(CharUpperW(PWideChar(chr)));
0063A909 0FB7C3           movzx eax,bx
0063A90C 50               push eax
0063A90D E8AAB1DDFF       call CharUpperW
```

Comment: Can you compare declaration of `CharUpperW` in 10.3 and 10.4 (unit Winapi.Windows.pas)?

Comment: @zed the declaration of CharUpperW in 10.3 and 10.4 is the same! LPWSTR = PWideChar; function CharUpperW(lpsz: LPWSTR): LPWSTR; stdcall;

Comment: 10.4 makes hidden string from single char and put pointer to this string to CharUpperW and it brakes all down.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok with your help I have find the answer...
Actully the functons `CharUpper` and `CharUpperW` are in `Winapi.Windows` unit and both calls the same API call `CharUpperW`.
But in Delphi version 10.4 of unit `Winapi.Windows` is new function overload:

```
function CharUpper(lpsz: LPWSTR): LPWSTR; overload; stdcall; external user32kernel name 'CharUpperW';
function CharUpper(tch: WideChar): WideChar; overload; stdcall;
begin
  Result := WideChar(IntPtr(CharUpperW(LPWSTR(IntPtr(tch)))));
end;
```

Compiler takes this overload function instead old one and result is described in my question.

To avoid this overload function we must correct typecast variable `Chr` to get right result:

```
var
  Chr     :Char; //Or WideChar 
begin
  Chr := 'a';   
  Chr := Char(CharUpper(LPWSTR(ord(Chr))));
```

EDIT:  We can also call CharUpperW API function like:

```
var
  Chr     :WideChar; //or Char
begin
  Chr := 'a';   
  Chr := Char(CharUpper(LPWSTR(ord(Chr))));
```

The disassembled code is the same:

```
umCommon.pas.109: Chr := 'a';
0063A906 66BB6100         mov bx,$0061
umCommon.pas.110: Chr := Char(CharUpperW(LPWSTR(ord(Chr))));
0063A90A 0FB7C3           movzx eax,bx
0063A90D 50               push eax
0063A90E E8A9B1DDFF       call CharUpperW
0063A913 8BD8             mov ebx,eax
```

Comment: Function `CharUpper` and overloading has nothing to do with it, but typecast `ord(Chr)` do. Open disassembled code again and look what happens.

Comment: @zed right and typecasted must be also `CharUpper` function, corected answer. The disassembled code is now the same.!

Comment: `Compiler takes this overload function instead old one` - no, it's wrong! In your example code you call `CharUpperW` directly, so compiler didn't use any overloading. Error was happening because of compiler new behavior. Adding typecast with `ord` you forced new compiler behave like previous.

Comment: @zed No functions `CharUpperW`  and `CharUpper` are the same! Check functions in unit `Winapi.Windows`. `CharUpperW`  is also overloaded!

Comment: I have not 10.4. If `CharUpperW` overloaded in the same way, then you can use it like `Chr := CharUpperW(Chr);` isn't it?

Comment: @zed No: `function CharUpper(tch: WideChar): WideChar; overload; stdcall;
begin
  Result := WideChar(IntPtr(CharUpperW(LPWSTR(IntPtr(tch)))));
end;`

Comment: I'm talking about `CharUpperW` not about `CharUpper`.

Comment: @zed: No it is the same: `function CharUpperW(tch: WideChar): WideChar; overload; stdcall;
begin
  Result := WideChar(IntPtr(CharUpperW(LPWSTR(IntPtr(tch)))));
end;`

Comment: So, why you can't use overloaded version `Chr := CharUpperW(Chr)` ?

Comment: @zed: because compiler error under Delphi 10.3: " [dcc32 Error] : E2010 Incompatible types: 'PWideChar' and 'Char' ", under Delphi 10.4 works fine.

Comment: @GJ. So just make your own overload for 10.3 so your code compiles in both versions.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau. Exactly, Chr := Char(CharUpper(LPWSTR(ord(Chr)))); compile under both versions on old way. Chr can be `Char` or `WideChar` type. Use of CharUpperW or CharUpper procude the same result.

Answer (score 4):

The Win32 `CharUpperW()` function does not take a single `WideChar` as input, only a `PWideChar`. But the *interpretation* of that pointer depends on whether its high-order word is zero (the low-order word contains a single char) or non-zero (the whole pointer is to a null-terminated string).

The only way that `CharUpperW(WideChar('a'))` can even compile, in any version, is if Embarcadero has added their own overload that takes a single `WideChar` as input (I don't have any 10.x versions installed to verify).

IMHO, `CharUpperW()` is a bit dangerous to use because of this abuse of a pointer. I would not trust it with typecasted literals, use a variable instead so you can ensure you are giving it exactly what it really wants:

```pascal
var
  chr : array[0..1] of WideChar;
begin
  chr[0] := 'a';
  chr[1] := #0;
  CharUpperW(chr);
end;
```

```pascal
var
  chr : WideChar;
begin
  chr := 'a';
  char := WideChar(CharUpperW(PWideChar(chr)));
end;
```

That being said, there are other functions in the RTL to handle this task, use those instead.

**UPDATE:** I’ve created a support ticket for this:

[RSP-31498: Bad codegen breaks Winapi.Windows.CharUpperW()](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-31498)

Comment: There is no overloaded version of `CharUpperW` in Delphi 10.3, but both variants compiled successful. Also, look at this disassembled code: https://imgur.com/OEZ3843 - compiler put char value onto the stack, not the pointer. It puts pointer in case when we call function with `WideChar('a')` which results in AV. What does all this mean?

Comment: Sorry but your code with WideChar second sample still get different output in version 10.4 than earlier versions of Delphi. Check correction of my answer...

Comment: I understand. 10.3 works correct - it puts single char value for `PWideChar('a')` or pointer for WideString input. Exactly what required by [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-charupperw). @GJ can you look in to disassembled code under 10.4? I think that compiler make something wrong with single-char input.

Comment: @GJ You should not edit answer, add it to your question instead.

Comment: Sorry I know... I was to fast and pressed Remy Lebeau edit instead mine... Corected

Answer (score 2):

Since Delphi 10.4 create hidden string and `CharUpperW` acts [different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-charupperw#return-value) when it works with single-char or null-terminated string input, you need to rewrite your code to make it consistent for 10.4 and 10.3 (and older) versions:

```
var
  s: string;
begin
  s := 'a';
  CharUpperW(@s[1]);
end;
```

---

P.S. Due to these difficulties, I would recommend you to use `UpperCase` / `AnsiUpperCase` from System.SysUtils.

Comment: Yeah... `UpperCase` / `AnsiUpperCase` are to slow for my purpoese.

Comment: `@s[1]` is the same as doing `PChar(s)`

Comment: @RemyLebeau It isn't. In first case compiler calls `UniqueStringU` and all works fine, in second case it calls `UStrToPWChar` and AV occurred.

Comment: @GJ. “*`UpperCase`/`AnsiUpperCase` are to slow for my purpose*” - Have you tried [`TCharHelper.ToUpper()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Character.TCharHelper.ToUpper) yet?

Comment: @ Remy Lebeau. No, I'm using upcase table: UpCaseTable :array[Char] of Char; wich is filled at beginning of program.